# Object can't exist without and outside another object

Tags: c#, oop, idisposable

I want to have a program in C# that object A can't be created without object B and also when object B is destroyed, object A would be demolished automatically. so existence of object A would be completely dependent on existence of Object B.

I am aware that it is possible to force A inside B's contractor, however I want to make it impossible to create A outside B in any part of the application. maybe a factory pattern? I am not sure how to limit other developers to create a class, or create it with certain criteria.

Comment: Your question would benefit from a small, runnable example illustrating what you tried. Now it pops up at the review stacks for being not a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have a program in C# that object A can't be created without object B

that part is easy - just make `A` have a constructor that takes `B`.

> and also when object B is destroyed, object A would be demolished automatically.

that part is not so trivial; in particular, **you don't control** garbage collection, nor do you control what references an `A` instance, so the most you can do is make `B` **dispose** `A`.

Indeed, if an `A` depends on a `B`, then `A` probably has a reference to a `B`. That means that if `A` is reachable (not garbage), then **neither is `B`** (because it can be reached via `A`), thus `B` wouldn't be collected in the first place. And if `B` *is* being destroyed, then we already know that the `A` is toast, by the same reasoning. From a certain perspective, this actually achieves everything you wanted.

The only sensible time to actually *do* something here (rather than just relying on the reachable graph) is in *disposal* of `B`. So at that point you've got something like:

```
class A : IDisposable {
    B _b;
    A(B b) { b.Register(this); _b = b; }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { _b = null; }
    void CheckDisposed() { if(_b == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(A)); }
    public void ActualMethod() {
        CheckDisposed();
        // do stuff
    }
}
class B : IDisposable {
    A _a;
    internal void Register(A a) {
        if(a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        if(_a != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("already has an A");
        _a = a;
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        var tmp = _a;
        _a = null;
        tmp?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, at this point the types are so inter-dependent that I question the purpose of having two types. There are ways to loosen this dependency and allow 0-* mapping, but it is such an odd requirement that I don't see the purpose of it.

Comment: the problem is that, I have a system in which the classes would be used by another programmers and I want to limit their options in creating an object without another object. even if I make A inside B contractor, it does't mean A can't be created in other part of program separately. I want to make it impossible to create A without B. Maybe a factory pattern?

Comment: @RoozbehHalvaei you'll notice I passed A *into* the constructor - I didn't create it internally, so to create a B you already need an A in the code above.